# Angular Post Reactive Form on server

Tags: angular, http, post

Hello so I'm tryin to add an Item to server but I got kind of stuck sending it to server

Here are some code snippets
This is the function in my add component that is called when the form is filled and somewhere here is the mistake

```
public onOkClick(priceListItemDTO): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.itemsService.AddItems(this.profileForm)
      .subscribe(params => {
        priceListItemDTO = this.profileForm;
      });
  }
```

The onOkClick uses this fuinction in my items service (There might be a mistake here but I'm pretty sure there is not. Maybe a little one

```
public AddItems(priceListItemDTO: FormGroup): Observable<PriceListItemDTO[]> {
  return this.apiService.post<PriceListItemDTO[]>(
  '/price-lists/' + ItemsService.PRICE_LIST_ID + '/items', priceListItemDTO);
```

And The AddItems uses ApiService this is 100% correct

```
public post<T>(endpoint: string, params = null): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(ApiService.URL + endpoint, params, {headers: this.getRequestHeaders()})
      .pipe(tap(null, err => this.interceptError(err)));
  }
```

So I'm trying to create another item I've tried I'm sure that the From is correct and there is a mistake in the first code snippet I've tried using push too but I failed at that too.
If you need me to clarify something I'll Happily do that

Comment: Have you inspected the network request and confirmed the form data is being sent over the wire to the server? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this needed a few changes as you can see

```
 priceListItemDTO: PriceListItemDTO[];   
     public onOkClick(): void {
            this.dialogRef.close();
            this.itemsService.AddItems(this.profileForm.value)
              .subscribe(params => {
                this.priceListItemDTO.push(this.profileForm.value);
              });
          }
```

here it just needed to formarray

```
public AddItems(priceListItemDTO: FormArray, plu: number): Observable<PriceListItemDTO[]> {
  return this.apiService.post<PriceListItemDTO[]>(
  '/price-lists/' + ItemsService.PRICE_LIST_ID + '/items', priceListItemDTO);
```

it all works as intended now